# Node (Error: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol)

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, linux, firebase

Under linux (termux installed on firetv)
The node program stops with an error as follows.
It is a program to watch the updating of data saved in Firebase Realtaime Database.
Please tell me how to solve it.

```
    ~ $ uname -a        #FireOS5 is based Android 5.1.
    Linux localhost 3.10.54+ # 1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Apr 23 21:32:34 UTC 2018 armv7l Android
    ~ $ npm install firebase-tools
    (omit some details)
    ~ $ firebase login
    (omit some details)
    ~ $ firebase init
    (omit some details)
    ~ $ node -v
    v9.11.1
    ~ $ echo $ PATH
    /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin:/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/applets
~ $ echo $ LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/system/lib:/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib
    ~ $ find / -name libz.so 2> / dev / null
    /system/lib/libz.so
~ $ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH = / system / lib: $ LD_LIBRARY_PATH
    ~ / $ node firebase-listener.js
    WARNING: linker: grpc_node.node: unused DT entry: type 0x6ffffef5 arg 0xb60
    /data/data/com.termux/files/home/rm_mini3/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/node_modules/grpc/src/grpc_extension.js:57
        throw e;
        ^
    
    Error: dlopen failed: can not locate symbol "inflate" referenced by "grpc_node.node" ...
        at Object.Module._extensions .. node (internal / modules / cjs / loader.js: 683: 18)
        at Module.load (internal / modules / cjs / loader.js: 566: 32)
        at tryModuleLoad (internal / modules / cjs / loader.js: 506: 12)
        at Function.Module._load (internal / modules / cjs / loader.js: 498: 3)
        at Module.require (internal / modules / cjs / loader.js: 598: 17)
        at require (internal / modules / cjs / helpers.js: 11: 18)
        at Object. <anonymous> (/ data / data / com.termux / files / home / rrm / mini 3 /
        at Module._ compile (internal / modules / cjs / loader.js: 654: 30)
        at Object.Module._extensions .. js (internal / modules / cjs / loader.js: 665: 10)
        at Module.load (internal / modules / cjs / loader.js: 566: 32)
```

### Supplement

The same source runs OK in another environment (ubuntu (WSL, intel windows)).

https://github.com/termux/termux-packages
I wonder if it is related to what is written at the bottom of the page.
can not locate symbol "inflate" referenced by "grpc_node.node"
Although grpc_node.node refers to "inflate", the library file
Does it mean that you can not load?Does that mean I have to change something to be statically linked?
Is it a path problem? or  do I need to compile something from the source?
I do not know exactly what to do.

/data/data/com.termux/files/home/rm_mini3/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/node_modules/grpc/src/grpc_extension.js

```
'use strict';

var binary = require ('node-pre-gyp / lib / pre-binding');
var path = require ('path');
var binding_path =
binary.find (path.resolve (path.join (__ dirname, '../ package.json'))));
var binding;
try {
binding = require (binding_path);
} catch (e) {
let fs = require ('fs');
let searchPath = path.dirname (path.dirname (binding_path));
let searchName = path.basename (path.dirname (binding_path));
let foundNames;
try {
foundNames = fs.readdirSync (searchPath);
} catch (readDirError) {
let message = `The gRPC binary module was not installed. This may be fixed by running" npm rebuild "
Original error: $ {e.message} `;
let error = new Error (message);
error.code = e.code;
throw error;
}
if (foundNames.indexOf (searchName) === -1) {
let message = `Failed to load gRPC binary module because it was not installed for the current system
Expected directory: $ {searchName}
Found: [$ {foundNames.join (',')}]
"Npm rebuild" on the current system
Original error: $ {e.message} `;
let error = new Error (message);
error.code = e.code;
throw error;
} else {
throw e; // HERE! the error 
}
}
module.exports = binding;
```